# Accessing private methods of a JS Function

Tags: javascript, function, constructor, javascript-objects

I have following javascript code

```
function MyFunc () {

    var add = function () {
        return "Hello from add";
    };

    var div = function () {
         return "Hello from div";
    };

    var funcCall =  function (obj) {

        if (!obj) {
            throw new Error("no Objects are passed");
        }
      return obj.fName();


    };

  return {
    func: function (obj) {
      funcCall(obj);
    }
  };

}

var lol = new MyFunc();
```

When `lol.func({fName: add});` is passed it should invoke the function private function `add` or when `lol.func({fName: div});` is passed it should invoke the private div function. What i have tried does not work. How can i achieve this.

[DEMO](https://jsbin.com/lalenayixo/edit?js,console)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Comment: I guess only `eval` could do what you want without updating your code a bit.

Comment: @Kyll This is not what i have asked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it's better to store your inner function in the object so you can easily access this with variable name. So if you define a function "map"

```
var methods = {
    add: add,
    div: div
};
```

you will be able to call it with `methods[obj.fName]();`.

Full code:

```
function MyFunc() {

    var add = function () {
        return "Hello from add";
    };

    var div = function () {
        return "Hello from div";
    };

    var methods = {
        add: add,
        div: div
    };

    var funcCall = function (obj) {

        if (!obj) {
            throw new Error("no Objects are passed");
        }

        return methods[obj.fName]();
    };

    return {
        func: function (obj) {
            return funcCall(obj);
        }
    };

}

var lol = new MyFunc();
console.log( lol.func({fName: 'add'}) );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `lol.func({fName: add})` add is resolved in the scope of evaluating this code, not in the scope of `MyFunc`. You have to either define it in that scope like:

```
function MyFunc () {

    var add = function () {
        return "Hello from add";
    };

    var div = function () {
         return "Hello from div";
    };

    var funcCall =  function (obj) {

        if (!obj) {
            throw new Error("no Objects are passed");
        }
      return obj.fName();


    };

  return {
    add: add,
    div: div,
    func: function (obj) {
      funcCall(obj);
    }
  };

}
var lol = new MyFunc();
lol.func({fName: lol.add});
```

Or use `eval`.